# Power dissipation in resistor from triangle wave

Tags: resistors, power-dissipation

How to calculate power dissipation through resistor from specific wave form?

Wave:  Triangle, 1V, 1kHz
Resistor: 10kohm

Q: What is the power dissipation in the resistor, considering frequencies up to 5kHz?

Is there a simple and more accurate way of calculation? 
In case I would like to understand/learn both.

Answer (score 1):

The full band formula:
P = (U^2)/3R  (U means the peak voltage of the triangle wave)

This is practically the same as if limited to 5th harmonic because the 7th or higher ones are so weak. The error is about 1,5%

The bandlimited version needs a fourier series expansion. The peak amplitude of Nth harmonic (N=1,3,5,7,....) is 8*U/(pi*N)^2 . The power of the Nth harmonic is (8*U/(pi*N)^2)^2/2R. Calculate this for N=1,3,and 5. Add the powers. You will end to 98.6% of the full band power.

Comment: Yes I need to limit to only include 3rd and 5th harmonic, as it's a theoretical question.

Comment: @bretddog new answer

Answer (score 1):

A triangular wave has odd (only) harmonics related to the fundamental like so: -

\$A_n = \dfrac{1}{n^2}A_1\$

So, the third harmonic is down at one-ninth of the amplitude of the fundamental. The fifth is at one-twenty-fifth etc...

> What is the power dissipation in the resistor, considering frequencies
>   up to 5kHz?

Work out the RMS voltage of 1st, 3rd and fifth harmonics together: -

\$RMS = \sqrt{1^2+ \frac{1}{9^2}+ \frac{1}{25^2}}\$ = 1.00695 volts

In other words, it produces a power into a resistor that is 1.395% higher than just a sine wave having the same fundamental amplitude.

On the other hand, if the triangle wave form is specified as having an amplitude 1 volt RMS then it's the same power irrespective of waveform shape.

Comment: The series coefficients are incorrect - each of them should be multiplied by 8*V/pi^2.  The tipoff is that 1 is the Vrms of a square wave with the same Vp, and a square wave at all but the points where it crosses the 0 volt line or touches the peak of the triangle is greater.  Same thing is true for a sine wave: its Vrms is .707 and it's everywhere bigger than the triangle.

Comment: I was trying to figure out this. But even 8V/pi^2*sqrt[(1/n)^2)] gives 0.87V. Shouldn't Vrms of a triangle wave be <.707 of a sine wave..?

Comment: @stretch if you read my answer I'm relating rms values and, in particular, I have stated that the sinewave value equates to the triangle case fundamental frequency. I don't see ny reason to complicate this by making the assumption that the numbers need to be peak values. If you think that using your numbers gives a different and more relevant answer then I look forward to that answer.

Comment: @bretddog my answer assumes the fundamental frequency for both triangle wave and sine wave have the same amplitude. I have stated this and I also stated the alternate scenario about rms produces the same power no matter what the waveform.

Comment: @bretddog 8V/pi^2 is .81 and that's the Vp of the 1st harmonic(AKA the fundamental). user287001 has the right values.  He modified his answer to show the effect of disregarding the higher harmonics, but his first cut was correct for a wide band answer. Curd has the correct general way of dealing with periodic, non-sinusoidal waveforms, but it doesn't adapt itself well to finding the power from the lowest 3 harmonics.

Comment: @Andy aka: I was trying to show why the RMS value of the triangle wave must be less than that of a sine wave or square wave of the same Vp.

Comment: @stretch clearly it has to be but that isn't necessarily what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

In general mean power of a periodic signal is
\$\overline P = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T P(t)dt = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T v(t) i(t) dt\$
where \$T\$ is the period of the signal.

Now you just have plug in your particular funtions for voltage \$v(t)\$ and current \$i(t)\$ and simplify and evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Find the instaneous power and integrate it over the whole cycle.

O a  3rd of the peak power.

Answer (score -1):

Power into a resistor is proportional to the square of the voltage.  Specifically:

W = V<sup>2</sup> / Ω

where W is the power in Watts, V the EMF in Volts, and Ω the resistance in Ohms.

So to find the power of a triangle wave (or any wave for that matter), square it, find the average of the squared value over some repeating period, then divide that by the resistance.

Note that this is the point of RMS voltage.  One way to think of RMS of a voltage waveform is the DC voltage that would result in the same power going into a resistive load.

This is your homework assignment, so I'm not going to do everything for you.  Hopefully you have enough now to proceed.